# How to add a description in the CMS for the posts index.php file in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to add a custom field in the admin for the posts page.

I'm currently pointing the reading post pages to my index.php file and I haven't got the usual input fields that you would find in a template. I am just left with a featured image and a title.

The question is how would I go about adding a field to this page in the admin so I can print it out in the index file?

It is worth pointing out that I am currently using custom advanced fields if this help towards my solution.

Ta

Comment: Do you mean a meta description?

Comment: Can someone point out why this has been down voted? its a perfectly good question. James Jones I basically need a wysiwig on the blog page in the admin however I can't get one to show without it being a template.

Comment: You can simply add a meta field to your post type. You have certain wordpress plugins for that, but you can also write your own. I did this with custom post types, but you can also do it by adding it to the post type excisting if i am not mistaken. See here for documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

Comment: Thanks but I've already answered my question with the information I wrote below

Answer (score 0):

So people can use this thread in the future I found a solution to my problem.

When you set the reading of post pages to a certain page it no longer becomes a page. This means that you have to access it in a different way which I was unaware of.

If you wish to access the data that is on the posts page then you have to use the below php:

```
$page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
```

This allows you to check for the ID on the page for posts which is the same page as mine.

Then if I want to get the title of that page I can do something like this in my php file:

```
<?php echo get_the_title($page_for_posts); ?>
```

And if you are using custom advanced fields which I am then you can put in a second parameter like so:

```
<?php the_field('blog-introduction', $page_for_posts); ?>
```

Many thanks